# PHP Invisible string

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have this array of string:

```
array(59) {
    [0]=> string(25) "shadowcores.twifysoft.net"
    [1]=> string(11) " "
}
```

Obviously there are 57 elements more. I need to know how can I remove this:

```
string(11) " "
```

There is no string to display but the string itself its not empty. How can I check for these types of values before adding them into my array?

Comment: Protip: Add `header('Content-Type: text/plain');` to the top of your script.

Comment: `if ($arr[$i] == ' ') { unset($arr[$i]); }`?

Comment: already tried that the thing is the string seems to have hidden characters or something

Comment: Perhaps there is some unicode in there? Apparently something thinks there are 11 characters (or bytes).

Comment: The trim array_filter seems to be working well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$array = array_filter($yourArray, 'trim');
```

Comment: @AmalMurali array_filter($yourArray, 'trim') will remove that ' ' element from the array while array_map('trim',$array) trim it to '' and still keep it in the array.

Comment: @PaulLo: Yeah, but however, the callback in your code is redundant, as it just repeats the default behavior.

Comment: @AmalMurali Yeah, if incorrectly use array_filter($yourArray, trim()) as my original post, it actually have the same effect as array_map('trim', $array)

Comment: @PaulLo:  `array_filter($yourArray, trim())` would never work, because `trim()` expects at least one parameter and you'll be passing none. The correct way to pass callback is: `array_filter($array, 'callback');`. My point was **this**: `array_filter()` by default filters out empty array elements, so the `trim` callback is redundant and not actually necessary.

Comment: @AmalMurali Oh yeah, as you said, I found array_filter($yourArray, trim()) would never work. But looks like we cannot just use array_filter($array) in this case since that ' ' blank string is not evaluated as an empty element.

Comment: By blank string ' ' I mean there is a space between two ' single quotes, unlike empty string, that element will not be removed by array_filter($yourArray)

Answer (score 3):

Loop through the array and check to see if the string is empty after trimming whitespace

```
if (empty(trim($string))) {
     // unset from array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) them beforehand or use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to get rid of the just-whitespace elements

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to skin this cat.

Personally, I'd go for running the variable through `trim()` and then check to see if this value is `empty()` or has a `strlen() == 0`. If this is the case, you can skip adding it to the array.

Comment: He explicitly tell us that `string(11) " "`.  Thus the string has 11 characters ... ?

Answer (score 2):

To remove empty array values, you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array_filter).

From the [manual page](http://php.net/array_filter):

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of array equal to FALSE (see [converting to boolean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)) will be removed.

So, simply call:

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

And if you want to remove whitespace from the beginning and end of all array values, you can use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$array = array_map('trim', $array);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is several options. to remove theses values from the array you can use that technique:

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
  if (trim($v) == '')
    unset($array[$k]);
}
```